# find IP and replace it in a batch script from php

Tags: php

I'm trying to find the value of ip which is "1.1.1.1" from a batch file with php.
This is the first line from my batch script.

```
SET ip="1.1.1.1"
```

After finding it I want it to be replaced with a new IP.
I have this:

```
$str=implode("",file('C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\script.bat'));
$fp=fopen('C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\script.bat','w');
$str=str_replace('1.1.1.1','127.0.0.0',$str);
fwrite($fp,$str,strlen($str));
```

The problem is that I need to find the value of ip to replace it. The value changes and I need to find it first in order to be able to replace it.
How do I find the value of variable IP and replace it?

Comment: if you can write that much php, sctapeing a text file should not be to hard. so what have you tried

Comment: What about `sed -i 's/SET ip="[0123456789]*\.[0123456789]*\.[0123456789]*\.[0123456789]*"/SET ip="127.0.0.7"/' 'C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/script.bat'`?

Comment: i struggled with str_replace but it needed to be preg_replace ...

Comment: @Eugen I'm on Windows

Comment: @usersubuser I thought even WIndows now has a BASH-capable subsystem?

Comment: i'm old fashioned with windows server 2008 r2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer was:

```
$str = preg_replace('/\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b/','127.0.0.0',$str);
```

Comment: But this is not an accurate regex, cause string like `256.256.302.333` will be treated as an 'IP address' which is not actually. An accurate one could be like this `^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$`

Answer (score 2):

Using SET will declare the proceeding variable as an environment variable. To access it in php try $_ENV['ip']

Comment: this is what I was looking for $str = preg_replace('/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/', '127.0.0.0',$str);

Comment: @usersubuser that code will match literally anything that even remotely resembles an IP address, including many things that are not. Additionally, the question stated *in the question* is answered by this. Perhaps you should clarify the question itself.